# bootstrap grid - mobile and desktop arrangement

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have following problem:
I want three columns side by side on desktop, displayed fullscreen.
On mobile devices I want three rows beneath displayed fullscreen.

Here is desktop sketch:
[image]

Here is mobile sketch:
[image]

And here is code what I have for now. it is working on desktop, but not on mobile devices.

```css
#eshop{
    background-color: red;
}

#truhlarna{
    background-color: blue;
}

#bahnak{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.col-md-4{
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
}

.col-xs-12{
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bakes Wood</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid kontejner">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="eshop" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">A</div>
                <div id="truhlarna" class="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-4">B</div>
                <div id="bahnak" class="col-xs-12  col-sm-4 col-md-4">C</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Although the concept is of using vh dimension unit. I have updated my code at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/rLXgOB)**

CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-md-4 {
    height: 33.33vh;
  }
}
```

As it said "On mobile devices I want three rows beneath displayed fullscreen." previously i assumed he want each section to be full screen, but after reading again i made my amendments but credit to zimsystem enjoy :)

Comment: I don't think this is good approach because this will be overridden the bootstrap functionality. so this will affect the whole app wherever the .col-md-4 used. But answer is upvoted how?

Comment: @kernallora Its just an idea to a person that he can solve his problem via these style.. He can create custom class to be specific to one section only. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use a media-query and `vh` for mobile devices..

```
.col-md-4{
     overflow: auto;
     height:100vh;
}    

@media (max-width:768px) {
        .col-md-4{
            height:33.33vh;
        }
    }
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/AUD3fMsx6P

Answer (score -1):

Combination of your answer worked it out.)

```css
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .col-md-4{
        overflow: auto;
        height:33.33vh;
    }
}

@media (min-width:769px) {
    .col-md-4{
        overflow: auto;
        height:100vh;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jyoti answer uses padding so this was not in their answer. It was in my demo.